# ASIHTTPRequest; installation issues

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am trying to install ASIHTTPRequest and i am having issues with libxml/HTMLParser, xmlsave, xpath and xpathInternals are missing.
I have already included the libxml2.2.7.3 framework and followed the guide on their website to the letter.

any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: i have included CFNetwork,MobileCoreServices,SystemConfiguration,libbz2,Foundation,Coregraphics,libxml as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>You note that you've followed the instructions to the letter, though I don't see **libz.1.2.3.dylib** in your post or in your comments. Are you certain you have libz.1.2.3?</s>

Note that it is not the same as libbz2 or libxml2. If you filter by dylibs it's right near the bottom.

---

**Edited to add the real answer, as discovered through a lengthy back-and-forth in the comments**

Adjust your Header Search Paths to: `${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2`, as explained in the special instructions for ASIWebPageRequest at: **[allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)**

Comment: i have removed everything and started it from scratch, now it works - not sure what went wrong, no build errors now, but when i try to use ASIHTTPRequest *request - get an error   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
do i have to include anymore stuff?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. You do need to #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" in your class, of course.

Comment: i have removed everything and started it from scratch, now it works - not sure what went wrong, no build errors now, but when i try to use ASIHTTPRequest *request - get an error   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:      objc-class-ref-to-ASIHTTPRequest in searchBar1ViewController.o; ld: symbol(s) not found
do i have to include anymore stuff?

Comment: Hi matthew, that ofcourse i did, i have include #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" in my class already. The error is only after that

Comment: Hmm. In the ASIHTTPRequest Google Group it appears that removing the external folder (with the ASIHTTP classes) and re-adding it has worked for some people. Here's one: http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/94a36911840a0076/411fab9a178db5d5

Comment: hmm, this is really troubling me. i have totally started a new project for testing, included all the frameworks, copied the classes into my project - and i have tons of errors without even writing a single line of code..the errors are same as my original post htmlparser.h,xmlsave.h,xpath.h,xpathInternals.h not found :( - trying to add a screen shot of my files to the main post

Comment: Ah, from the screenshot I see that you're using the experimental ASIWebPageRequest (the web page downloader). Are you certain that's what you want? If so, have you adjusted your Header Search Paths: ${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2 ? See the special instructions for  ASIWebPageRequest here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

Comment: Ah okay - no, i do not with to use webpage request, i have removed webpagerequest and added the headersearchpath in the configuration; worked like a charm, thanks a lot matthew.. how do i set your post as the answer?

Comment: Glad that solved it! Click the checkmark next to the answer to give credit for the right answer.

Comment: the check mark next to your comment does'nt appear, so i could'nt pick it as an answer, i voted for the comment though:) thanks matthew

Comment: Not next to the comment, next to the answer. You're most welcome, glad it helped.

Comment: To whomever just downvoted this answer, would you please take a moment to explain why in a comment? I've got no problem with being told I gave a bad answer, but I'd at least like to know what was wrong with it.

Comment: Note to all: `ASIWebPageRequest` is not a compulsory class. If you don't need it, delete its reference

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" in your Header Search Paths inside the build settings of your project

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [ASIHttpRequest Setup Instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions):

> Open the Build Phases tab, expand the box labeled Link Binary With Libraries then click the plus button.
>
> [image: linkbin]

...and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

ASIWebPageRequest is not necessary unless you specifically need this, in fact its currently experimental.  If you do want to use it you need to add the libxml framework.