# XCode can't locate #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h" IOS 4.3

Tags: ios, import, asihttprequest

I am following a tutorial in order to connect my app to facebook. When I import JSON and ASIHTTPRequest libraries I cant call headers to use function in that libraries

[image: import problem]

I have added "${SRCROOT}" with quotes two  the Header Search Path Debug and Header Search Path Release

[image: settings]

It didnt work.

i have also looked at this to questions but couldnt make it done
[ASIHTTPRequest; installation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301143/asihttprequest-installation-issues)

[Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I see that they're already dragged there, but I would prefer if you can expand those folders and show us the files. Also, double check the file names :)

Comment: That was the first thing I did when I saw the errors. They are all there.

Comment: Can you add a link to the project files? That would be really helpful :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant believe how dummy Xcode works I have just deleted all JSON, Classes and Reachability folders and copied again all the headers without the folders  now it works. I can't understand why headers work outside offolders? but

anyways if anyone tries all other solution and it doesnt work maybe this solution can work.
[image]

Comment: You let Xcode copy them, right? You shouldn't've done this. You now have an epic mess to clean up. Delete all the extra files and fix your search path.

Comment: Yes Xcode copied them like in the tutorial, I guess I will start all over because that was an experiment to learn how to connect facebook.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably for the best. In your original screenshot, it looks like you picked "Copy items" and "Create folder references". Instead, leave "Copy items" off and pick "Create groups." :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the folder containing the AFNetworking headers to **User Header Search Paths**.

It looks like that would be `$(SRCROOT)/AFNetworking/AFNetworking` for you.

(Also, same applies to your JSON library.)