# 'libxml/HTMLparser.h' file not found in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, libxml2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASIHTTPRequest; installation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301143/asihttprequest-installation-issues)

I've followed the [setup tutorial](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) step by step but I get this error: `'libxml/HTMLparser.h' file not found`. I've also [cloned the libxml library](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/), but it doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301143/asihttprequest-installation-issues

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've fixed it by adjusting the Header Search Paths to: `${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2`, you can find it in [ASIWebPageRequest instructions](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest).